# why some Github repositories can't be Imported properly in colab while others do?(not all public Github repositories are visible for Importing)

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I have problem with having a specific repository from Github imported in google colab. the problem is the repository contains no files in it to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Right Click > Open With > Colaboratory" option is available for any GitHub repository which includes a `ipyng` notebook file.

See [Loading Public Notebooks Directly from GitHub](https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/notebooks/colab-github-demo.ipynb#scrollTo=-pVhOfzLx9us).

[image: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*Sm0CLQDJjX0uJMMjLuuhYA.png]

<sup>(Image from "[Cloning Github Repo to Google Colab](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-tensorflow-keras-pytorch.html/2)")</sup>